# Linq query is super slow?

Tags: .net, linq, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I copied the sql query built by linq from sql profiler here is what's annoying about it:

1. It prefixes select ..columnNames.. from (select ..columnNames.. from ( select cNames from view) 
   Comments: the 2 select statements here are unnecessary.
2. this query takes 14 seconds to execute
3. when I remove the last line, containing all the params like the @p_*linq*_0 .. and fill the param values in where condition and execute the very same dynamic query it takes 1 sec or less. Even otherwise this query is taking 0 sec when performed from sql studio. This is so lame of linq.

I might move this to stored proc but I'm scared of using linq now

After further research i found out:

Query 1 :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * from TableView WHERE Id = @Id', N'@Id int', @Id = 1
```

Query 2:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * from TableView WHERE Id = 1'
```

Query 1 takes 12 seconds, Query 2 takes 0 second. This explains why linq query is slow. So now, does that mean I should always use stored procedures or am I missing something?

Why can't Microsoft fix Linq query building, how difficult is it to parse that string and replace the param values instead of passing those params as arguments to sp_executesql

Comment: What query are you talking about?

Comment: Without seeing either the LINQ query or the generated SQL, it's very hard to give you any help.

Comment: SQL caching might be responsible for the difference in execution time, assuming you tried your version second. Of course, it will depend on your setup and query.

Comment: What is daysRange? is it supposed to be v.daysRange?

Comment: @Aducci no its a string variable coming from application

Comment: @everybody Please let me know why you want to close this question?

Comment: @WhoIsNinja - Initially your question seemed like more of a complaint and didn't have enough detail or context.  With your recent edits I think it's pretty clear and this should definitely be reopened.

Comment: Your first query should not be taking 12 seconds to execute, under any circumstances (unless you're running SQL Server on a computer that's twelve years old, or the database is very large AND `Id` is not indexed). Do you have an index on `Id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm with you.  I mean, you could probably uncover the reason for this catastrophic performance hit you've discovered and find a remedy.  But in practice this sort of thing happens with Linq to SQL and spending this extra time to optimize your Linq statement so that the SQL query is more performant on the back-end kind of defeats the purpose.  Linq is supposed to make things easier.

Personally I use Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework for performing CRUD operations on single records.  And then with any large `SELECT` statements I'll simply write a stored proc as I've always done.  This seems to be a good compromise between productivity and performance that has worked well for me.

EDIT:
In fact the Entity Framework guys anticipated this.  And Entity Framework works pretty well with stored procedures.  You can [add a stored proc to your Entity Framework model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx) and get all that strongly typed goodness.  Then you can call that stored proc from code.

Comment: You can add stored procedures to Linq to SQL also. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should build the Where predicate dynamically taking out the Application specific daysRange
like so

```
var query = from v in tableView
            where v.Id == Id
            orderby v.RDate descending
            select v;

if(!daysRange.Equals("All"))
{
  query = query.Where(v => v.RdDate >= fromDate && v.RDate <= toDate);
}

query.ToList();
```

Comment: thats not going to make any difference Sir, I've tried everything. The question boils down to what I have updated in my question under "after further research."

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TableView), "v");
Expression equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Id"), Expression.Constant(Id));
Expression<Func<TableView, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lamda<Func<TableView, bool>>(equalsExpression, parameter);

var query = from v in tableView
            orderby v.RDate descending
            select v;

if(!daysRange.Equals("All"))
{
  query = query.Where(v => v.RdDate >= fromDate && v.RDate <= toDate);
}

query.Where(predicate).ToList();
```